# Difference between vite-plugin-electron and vite-electron-plugin

Tags: electron, vite

I'm trying to create an electron application with vite and I saw that there are these two vite plugins that are maintained by the same developer.

So I was wondering which one to use for my needs, in which case it is necessary to use one than the other

**vite-plugin-electron** vs **vite-electron-plugin**

[GitHub: vite-plugin-electron](https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-plugin-electron)

[GitHub: vite-electron-plugin](https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-electron-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**vite-plugin-electron vs vite-electron-plugin**
see: https://github.com/electron-vite/vite-plugin-electron/issues/107